# Fenugreek Sprouts - How am I doing? Am I done?

Tags: sprouting

12 hours ago

[image: 4th day sprouts]

Now

[image: 4.5 day sprouts]

They're definitely slowing down. They're pleasant as is, I could throw them into a salad or sandwich right now and they would be a nice addition. I'd like them even better if they would grow longer, fatter tails (heads?), but I don't want to go too far and wake up to dead stuff. Should I keep going or quit while I'm ahead? I think I first soaked them 4.5 days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Sprout People](http://sproutpeople.org/fenugreek.html). sprouting fenugreek should require about 2-3 days, which you are already passed.

They show pictures of the various stages; yours look quite similar to their "ready to harvest" picture:

[image]

The sample ones show a sprout length of about 2.5 - 3 times the length of the initial seed; the ones you show are close to 3-4 times as long.  This would suggest they are quite ready.

Note that in some sense, sprouting is a zero-sum game.   They are not rooted in soil, and so cannot absorb any nutrients.  Any growth of the sprout is paid for by consuming the calories and nutrition in the initial seed.  Waiting too long will just cause them to die.

Comment: Hmm, mine were barely poking their heads out at 2 days. Maybe it's because I keep my home quite cool (I'm right about 65F). At any rate, they're tasty as is, so into the fridge they go. Thanks.